# Android - How to create an expand fragment transition

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction, android-transitions

My application has the following design paradigm: One activity hosting fragments that display content.

One fragment holds a RecyclerView, and inside that Recyclerview I have CardViews that display content. I am trying to create a fragment transition so when a user clicks on a CardView, it expands/transforms that cardview into the next fragment.

How could I do this?

I have successfully created transitions from one fragment to another but I can't seem to find a transition that does this.

Comment: Reviving the dead here. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @IshaanGarg Unfortunately I have not :-( I moved to server side programming now lol.